# How to find an subset from the start of a collection with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Given a sequence of objects (I'll use strings in this example for simplicity) I'd like to know if the sequence is a subset of another sequence where order matters (I know subset isn't the correct word, so hopefully someone can enlighten me of the correct term!)

Basically say I had a sequence

AABBCDEFG

I want to match other list of strings up to that one in such a way that their position in the sequence matters (the first position in both strings should have the same object, then it would check the following string, etc). so AAB would be a subset and so would AABBC but not BCD.

It's obviously a really simple algorithm to write with a for loop, for example:

```
        bool List1ContainedInList2(List<String> list1, List<String> list2)
        {
            // list1 should be the same size or smaller than list2
            if (list1.Count > list2.Count)
                return false;

            // in order all objects should be equal
            for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list1[i]!= list2[i])
                    return false;
            }

            // all reqs met
            return true;
        }
```

but I keep discovering how many cool and fun things I can do with LINQ, and I'm wondering if there is a simple way to use LINQ to accomplish this? How would you do the above?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure you mean `i < list1.Count`...

Comment: @Ani - yes, just fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to "trim" the bigger list to a sequence of the right length and then use the [**`SequenceEqual`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) operator:

```
return list1.Count <= list2.Count && list2.Take(list1.Count)
                                          .SequenceEqual(list1);
```

Alternatively, we could focus on the indices (closest approach to your posted code):

```
return list1.Count <= list2.Count && Enumerable.Range(0, list1.Count)
                                               .All(i => list1[i] == list2[i]);
```

On .NET 4.0, we could [**`Zip`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) the sequences up (although `Zip` has the nice property that it stops streaming after the end of either sequence has been reached, we *still* need the `Count` equality check):

```
return list1.Count <= list2.Count && list1.Zip(list2, (s1, s2) => s1 == s2)
                                          .All(b => b);
```

or:

```
// This is an interesting one...
return list1.Zip(list2, (s1, s2) => s1 == s2)
            .Count(b => b) == list1.Count
```

All of the options I've mentioned *except* for the final one quick-reject, i.e. they will stop enumerating and return `false` when the first mismatch is found.

Comment: Why do you need `list1.Count <= list2.Count` on the `Zip` example?

Comment: You don't, but it's a quick catch for a false.

Comment: @Gabe, @ Mike M.: You *do* need the check because of the OP's requirements: the method should return `false` if `list1` is bigger than `list2`, *even if* their elements are equal up to the end of `list2`. So the nice property of the `Zip` operator doesn't help here.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I forgot that Zip will stop at the end of either list. Apologies :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
return list1.Take(list2.Count).SequenceEqual(list2);
```